# I need to improve python function that works with loops and string how it does?

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, optimization

I have such problem I have this piece of code on python2.7. It works approximately 60 seconds for object with slightly more than 70000 items in the object. How it works? It gets an object with paths to another objects and convert them to the ASCII strings. I think the problem why it is so slow is loops.

```
def createPath(self, path, NameOfFile ):
        temp = []
        for j in range( path.shape[0] ): 
            rr = path[j][0]
            obj = NameOfFile[rr]
            string = ''.join(chr(i) for i in obj[:])
            string = string.replace("aaaa","bbbb")      
            temp.append(string)
        return ( np.array(temp) )
```

It is not my own code, I found it in the Web  so what my question is ? How to make this piece of code faster ? I haven't huge experience in the python, but maybe there some useful libraries or tricks that may help. I appreciate all help, any ideas may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying loop hoisting might improve performance. Let's assume that `NameOfFile` is a list (the case if it is a dict is similar) and all of the entries in `NameOfFile` will be accessed and that the length of `NameOfFile` is most of the time smaller than `path.shape[0]`, so we can compute the transformations on them once:

```
def createPath(self, path, NameOfFile ):

    NameOfFile_ = []
    for obj in NameOfFile:
        name = ''.join(chr(i) for i in obj)
        name = name.replace("aaaa","bbbb")
        NameOfFile_.append(name)

    temp = []
    for j in range(path.shape[0]): 
        rr = path[j][0]
        temp.append(NameOfFile_[rr])

    return np.array(temp)
```

Comment: And now get rid of the anti-pattern `for j in range(path.shape[0]):`. Iterate over the objects itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same idea used by @DanD., but trying to avoid the for loops:

```
def createPath(self, path, NameOfFile):
    NameOfFile_ = [''.join(chr(i) for i in obj).replace("aaaa", "bbbb") for obj in NameOfFile]
    return np.array(NameOfFile_[obj[0]] for obj in path))
```

the interpreter overhead should decrease, although I have no way to check performance --in fact, I am not even sure that `for obj in path` is valid in this scenario.